# How can I gracefully handle php ftp login error

Tags: php, ftp

I get a server error on the ftp_login line of the following code. How can I gracefully handle connection/login failure?

```
$serverAddress = 'ftp.someServerAddress';
$connId = ftp_connect($serverAddress);
if($connId) {
    if (ftp_login($connId, 'UserName', 'password')) {
        // do some stuff
    } else {
        echo 'login failed';
    }
} else {
    echo 'connection failed';
}
```

Comment: One of the few times when the [error suppression operator `@`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) may be acceptable.

Comment: It's sad, but it's true @JonStirling

Comment: Yup, PHP 7 said they're moving to throwing Error exceptions, but the ftp library is still using the age old warnings... `@` is the way to go (just tested on PHP 7.1.0alpha2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work.

```
if( ! @ftp_login( $connection, 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD' ) ){
        die( 'Bad login, but no PHP warning thrown.');
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-login.php

Sorry forgot to add that the `@` symbol before function will suppress errors just as @John Stirling said before me in the comments.